# datetime object updated when editing in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, rails-admin

So I have a `Restaurant` table in my PostgreSQL DB hosted on Heroku, that has among others two `datetime` columns: `opens` and `closes` which represent the schedule of each restaurant.

I use [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/) with my Rails backend. Every time I want to edit a Restaurant, e.g. to change the Restaurant's `phone_number` (*NB: without touching either `opens` or `closes`*), both `opens` and `closes` get updated when I save the modifications and get one hour more. E.g. if `opens` for a specific restaurant was 12:00 and `closes` was 14:00, then it becomes 13:00 and 15:00.

Again, without changing `opens` or `closes` myself at all.

It probably has something to do with my timezone: in `application.rb`, I have this:

```
# timezone
config.time_zone = 'Paris'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

# languages

config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

what can I do to avoid datetime update ?

EDIT:

version used:

- rails (5.1.6)
- rails_admin (1.4.2)

Comment: Can you post the Rails and Rails Admin version?

Comment: hi @DimitriusLachi, I edited my post to add versions :)

Comment: hey @DimitriusLachi, using your deleted solution but setting timezone to `London` instead of `Paris` seems to do the trick ! it is not a perfect solution as I should be able to get the right timezone AND update my tables without this kind of problem. But that should be good for now.

Comment: Nice, i repost, the answer, i will update to put this explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a githubGist to explicitly set your timezone to RailsAdmin:

```
# Credits for https://gist.github.com/jackdesert/7090731
# rails_admin.rb

require 'rails_admin/config/fields/base'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Fields
      module Types
        class Datetime < RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Base

           def value
             value_in_default_time_zone = bindings[:object].send(name)
             return nil if value_in_default_time_zone.nil?
             pacific_time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Europe/Paris')
             value_in_default_time_zone.in_time_zone(pacific_time_zone)
           end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This require your config timezone in `staging.rb` and `production.rb` files, and you have to precompile assets in your deploy

Comment: thank you for your help ? what would be the one for Paris then ? `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Europe/Paris')` ?

Comment: According https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html is this, updated. Tell me if this works :)

Comment: I get an error when starting the server after I added this to my `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

Comment: Did you forgot to copy some 'end`?

Comment: indeed haha I was missing one `end` keyword at the end.

Comment: I didn't work though, I still get one more hour when saving an edited restaurant :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186851/discussion-between-jules-corb-and-dimitrius-lachi).